# Confluent Jdbc Sink Connector conditional update

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I,

i have to read message from Kafka and perform insert/update to Oracle database using Confluent Jdbc Sink Connector.

In the message, for every fields, I have a time stamp. So the message struct will be:

```
{
  "fieldA": "value",
  "timestampFieldA":12456789
}
```

i have to update the record if the timestampFieldA is after the value already saved in db. Is it possible?

Thanks